# Неправильная работа классов css

Tags: html, css

Проблема с работой css. Почему тег p с классом cite не работает? Написал всё правильно, проверил через ideone, работает нормально. Но почему-то у меня классы CSS браузер как будто не видит(вообще, все теги не видит почему-то). Вот пример кода. В CSS все контейнеры кроме p.cite из другого php файла. Сборка OpenServer, но не думаю что проблема может быть в нём. Когда использую тег style внутри php файла и пишу туда стиль текста, то он работает. А если делать стиль через класс и подключение css стилей, то ни один стиль не работает почему-то. Хотя картинка в контейнере body прогружается нормально. Ничего не понимаю, путаница полная. 
Сейчас вообще удалил из файла css все контейнеры, сохранил, и всё равно ничего на странице не изменилось.

```css
body {
  background: url(imgs/background_page.png) no-repeat;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

p.cite {
  background: #D9FFAD;
  color: green;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE  HTML>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <link href="style_main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <p align="center">
    <div>
      <p class="cite">
        Информация
      </p>
    </div>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: какая у вас структура проекта?

Comment: Проверьте подключение css-файла

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев да тут не в этом суть: просто что бы я не изменил в коде css, всё равно не меняется ничего.

Comment: @DaemonHK проверял несколько раз. Проверял код через ideone, всё работает как надо. Но когда запускаю файл на сервере, то никаких визуальных изменений на странице нету, хотя код я меняю и файл сохраняю.

Comment: @SnoopDoggyDog, как раз суть в структуре проекта

Comment: @SnoopDoggyDog если у вас css файл лежит не в одной папке с html файлом, то ваш html файл просто не видит файл css

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев все файлы лежат в одной папке.

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer Есть два php файла, к которым я подключаю css файл. Первоначально стили работали нормально. Сейчас же если полностью стереть код из файла css(который подключен к этим php файлам), то на странице не меняется ничего(файл я сохранял). Это вкратце, чтобы поняли суть.

Comment: То есть, что бы я не изменял в файле CSS, страница всё равно остаётся такой же! Подключение файла проверял. Файлы лежат в одной папке. Единственный вариант заставить это корыто поехать - использовать стили внутри php файла с помощью тега style, а не подключать его извне.

Comment: @SnoopDoggyDog а как вы подключаете css файлы к файлам php? можно код?

Comment: да у тебя явно ошибка в подключении. Открой консоль (хром -> F12) и там увидишь ошибки. Скорее всего увидишь ошибку в подключении файла

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев 
<head>
  <link href="style_main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
во втором файле то же самое

Comment: Повторюсь: файлы лежат в одной папке. При редактировании файлы сохраняю. Подключение работает(ибо если бы подключение не работало, то картинка на странице не загружалась, так как её подключение идёт в файле css). Проблема в чём-то другом, и я не понимаю в чём

Comment: @SnoopDoggyDog попробуйте вместо этого вот так echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style_main.css'>";

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев не помогает. Щас файл css пустой абсолютно, но стили на странице всё равно работают(некоторые). Магия какая-то...

Comment: никакой магии нет. 
1) пробуй кэш очистить. 2) открывай инспектор кода и смотри откуда стили идут. 3) во вкладке sources посмотри какие файлы подключаются

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть Спасибо Вам огромное! После очистки кэша всё заработало, и стили стрельнули. Здоровья и доброты! :)

Comment: `<p align="center">    <div>      <p ...` - это не валидно. Нельзя вкладывать в параграфы div, а внутри еще раз параграф. браузер это исправляет на другую структуру - посмотрите в браузере получающийся DOM

Comment: @SnoopDoggyDog на здоровье  )))

Comment: @TotalPusher уже исправил это

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь два вероятных решения этой проблемы:

1. Проверить путь к стилям `<link href="style_main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`.
2. Жесткая очистка кеша.

Comment: Вопрос уже решён очисткой кэша, но всё равно спасибо Вам за помощь. Держите галочку))

Comment: @SnoopDoggyDog спасибо!